# Deserializing JSON data

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am currently trying to parse some JSON data.  This is the format of the JSON string that I am getting:

```
{
  "messageFormat": "JSON",
  "messageArguments": [
    {
      "signUpModal": {
        "Id": 0,
        "FirstName": null,
        "LastName": null,
        "UserName": null,
        "Email": "<email address>",
        "RoleId": null,
        "Password": "<password>",
        "IsActive": null,
        "SecretKey": null,
        "Token": null,
        "Role": null,
        "RolePermissions": null,
        "ImagePath": null,
        "CurrentDate": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I created two classes to match this data structure:

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string messageFormat { get; set; }
    public List<SignUpModal> messageArguments { get; set; }
}

public class SignUpModal
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int? RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public int? SecretKey { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string RolePermissions { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string CurrentDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I use `var param = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parameter>(tempData);` no error is through and the `MessageFormat` filed correctly shows "JSON".  The `MessageArguments` field also contains an instance of the `SignUpModal` class, however all the fields in the `SignUpModal` class are `null`.

I've tried modify the class structures various ways but then the data won't even deserialize.  I'm not sure what why the data for the `messageArguments` field isn't being pulled correctly.  Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your object inside the array `messageArguments` is not a `SignUpModal`, it's an object with a property `signUpModal` that is a `SignUpModal`

Comment: Compare your code with what this generates: http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a class.  Add this class to your model:

```
public class MessageArgument
{
    public SignUpModal signUpModal { get; set; }
}
```

Then change this line in the `Parameter` class:

```
public List<SignUpModal> messageArguments { get; set; }
```

To this:

```
public List<MessageArgument> messageArguments { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Contract mismatch. You should either change JSON to:

```
{
    "messageFormat": "JSON",
    "messageArguments": [
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "FirstName": null,
        "LastName": null,
        "UserName": null,
        "Email": "<email address>",
        "RoleId": null,
        "Password": "<password>",
        "IsActive": null,
        "SecretKey": null,
        "Token": null,
        "Role": null,
        "RolePermissions": null,
        "ImagePath": null,
        "CurrentDate": null
    }]
}
```

Or change the entity

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string messageFormat { get; set; }
    public List<MessageArgument> messageArguments { get; set; }
}

class MessageArgument {
    public SignUpModal SignUpModal {get; set;}
}

public class SignUpModal
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int? RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public int? SecretKey { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string RolePermissions { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string CurrentDate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Matt Burland has pointed out, the issue is with `messageArguments`.
If you also use the resource provided by Robert Harvey you also see a difference in the object structure you have created.

`Parameter` should be comprised of

```
public string messageFormat { get; set; }
public List<MessageArgument> messageArguments { get; set; }
```

You will also need a

```
{
    public SignUpModal signUpModal { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using wrong class generator. I've copy your json to [jsonutils](http://jsonutils.com/) and it give my this model:

```
public class SignUpModal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public object FirstName { get; set; }
    public object LastName { get; set; }
    public object UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public object RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public object IsActive { get; set; }
    public object SecretKey { get; set; }
    public object Token { get; set; }
    public object Role { get; set; }
    public object RolePermissions { get; set; }
    public object ImagePath { get; set; }
    public object CurrentDate { get; set; }
}

public class MessageArgument
{
    [JsonProperty("signUpModal")]
    public SignUpModal SignUpModal { get; set; }
}

public class Parameter
{
    [JsonProperty("messageFormat")]
    public string MessageFormat { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("messageArguments")]
    public IList<MessageArgument> MessageArguments { get; set; }
}
```

Note that this code generator allow you to have PascalCase for properties by adding `JsonProperty` attribute

Now if you deserialize your input you will see non-null `Email` and `Password`:

```
var input = "{\r\n  \"messageFormat\": \"JSON\",\r\n  \"messageArguments\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"signUpModal\": {\r\n        \"Id\": 0,\r\n        \"FirstName\": null,\r\n        \"LastName\": null,\r\n        \"UserName\": null,\r\n        \"Email\": \"<email address>\",\r\n        \"RoleId\": null,\r\n        \"Password\": \"<password>\",\r\n        \"IsActive\": null,\r\n        \"SecretKey\": null,\r\n        \"Token\": null,\r\n        \"Role\": null,\r\n        \"RolePermissions\": null,\r\n        \"ImagePath\": null,\r\n        \"CurrentDate\": null\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parameter>(input);

Console.WriteLine(result.MessageArguments.First().SignUpModal.Email); // will print "<email address>"
```